# Add id to tag based on text it contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, replace, contains

I need to add an "id" to the h2 based on the text it contains. What I have is not working.

Starts like this

```
<h2>Revision 3</h2>
```

Scripts runs

```
$('h2:contains(" Revision 3 ")').replaceWith( "<h2 id="rev3">Revision 3</h2>");
```

Ends like this

```
<h2 id="rev3">Revision 3</h2>
```

Comment: Do i read question wrong or something because as far as i get you get what you asked for in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quote a string within a string using the string delimiters...so you can't *use* `"` inside a string delimited with `"`, but you *could* use `'` inside a string delimited with `"`). For example:

```
$('h2:contains(" Revision 3 ")').replaceWith( "<h2 id='rev3'>Revision 3</h2>");
```

Should work. Also, the spaces at the beginning, and end, of the string should be removed, since they're not in the string you're looking for:

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').replaceWith( "<h2 id='rev3'>Revision 3</h2>");
```

And, finally, would it not be easier to use something like:

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').attr('id','rev3');
```

Given that an `id` **must** be **unique within a document** it's maybe also worth limiting the selector to only one element:

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').eq(0).attr('id','rev3');
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Thank you for explaining to you what I had done wrong in my first script. Yes your way was so much easier I'm new to jquery and I was trying to make it too hard. Really thanks again.

Comment: @Ashlee, you're absolutely welcome; glad to have been of help to you :)

Comment: @Ashlee, incidentally, if this, or any other, answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting (click on the `✓` beside) the answer that most helpful to you, and up-voting (click on the `▲`) that answer, and/or others, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('h2').each(function ()
{
    if ($(this).text() == "Revision 3")
        $(this).attr('id','rev3');
}
```

Loops through all h2 tags, if the tag text is `Revision 3` it set the id to `rev3`

Answer (score 2):

Or if you just want to add ID to it you might use something faster like:

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').attr('id','rev3');
```

Comment: How would I go about something more dynamic which detects the text and adds the id from text

Answer (score 1):

I think the extract spaces at the begin and end of Revision 3 are creating an issue.

Try this:

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').replaceWith( "<h2 id="rev3">Revision 3</h2>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h2:contains("Revision 3")').attr("id", "rev3");
```